# Correct setup for a Laravel resource of a jsonb column?

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I have a jsonb column in Postgres that I'm trying to make use of with Laravel. When the resource itself is returned (rest, etc), the value for that column is returned null:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "partner_uuid": "bc844aa7-283e-4b82-8188-2f8764bc9d59",
            "metadata": null
        }
    ]
}
```

From the backend, this row definitely is non-null:

```
bc844aa7-283e-4b82-8188-2f8764bc9d59 | {"test": "test"}
```

I'm not very familiar with Laravel, and so I'm struggling a bit. The problem seems to be in the resource itself, which has a single function:

```
class PartnerMetadataResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'partner_uuid' => $this->partner_uuid,
            'metadata' => $this->metadata,
        ];
    }
}
```

If the metadata column is any other column type, this code seems sufficient to return the value as expected. I've tested with integers, text/varchar (and even the other column which is type uuid).

What is needed to return a value for that column? Either as escaped text, or as proper nested json?

Comment: Have you tried getting a dump from the eloquent model that is being transformed by this resource? In the controller dd() the model and check whether it has the data. Because as of now we know that there is data in the DB, but we don't know whether Laravel has fetched that data from the DB and somehow lost it when turning it into a resource or it didn't fetch it at all.

Comment: @A.Rahimi I hadn't. Thanks for the tip, I've got some leads to work from now.